# Flowlayout Panel hidden by other controls- Winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Flowlayout panel in a Winform.
Checkboxes are added dynamically to it.

The flowlayout panel size get bigger with each added checkbox and been hidden by other controls.

[image]

What property of the Flowlayout panel should I change on order to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set autoscroll = true for your flow layout panel.